# Enable/Disable Offline File Sync

Tags: function, powershell, windows-10

Here is the script from the site I found and I wanted to know if there is a way to improve it as when it's running I get this:

## Configure Offline files on localhost …

Disable offline files failed with

[image: Disable Offline File Sync]

## Configure Offline files on localhost …

Enable offline files failed with
reboot required

[image: Enable OfflineFile Sync]

I mean it does what it suppose to do just that message is annoying

This is as it was originally typed:

```
param($computer=”localhost”, $a, $help)


function funline ($strIN)
{
 $num = $strIN.length
 for($i=1 ; $i -le $num ; $i++)
  { $funline += “=” }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow $strIN 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor darkYellow $funline
}

function funHelp()
{
$helpText=@”
DESCRIPTION:
NAME: EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 
Enables or disables offline files on a local or remote machine.
A reboot of the machine MAY be required. This information will
be displayed in the status message once the script is run.

PARAMETERS: 
-computer Specifies name of the computer upon which to run the script
-a(ction) < e(nable), d(isable) >
-help     prints help file

SYNTAX:
EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -computer MunichServer -a e

Enables offline files on a computer named MunichServer

EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -a d

Disables offline files on local computer

EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -help ?

Displays the help topic for the script

“@
$helpText
exit
}

function funtranslatemethod($a)
{
 switch($a)
  {
   “e” { $global:m = $true 
         $global:msg = “Enable offline files” 
       }
   “d” { 
        $global:m = $false
        $global:msg = “Disable offline files” 
       }
  default{ 
          $global:msg = “$a is not an allowed response`n” 
 }
  }
}

if($help){ funline(“Obtaining help …”) ; funhelp }
if(!$a)
   {
    $(throw “You must supply an action. try this:
EnableDIsableOfflineFiles.ps1 -help ?”)
   }
$global:msg =$global:m = $null
funtranslatemethod($a)

$objWMI = [wmiclass]”\\$computer\root\cimv2:win32_offlinefilescache”
funline(“Configure Offline files on $computer …”)
$rtn = $objwmi.enable($m)
if($rtn.returnvalue -eq 0)
 {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor green “$msg succeeded”
 }
ELSE
 {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor red “$msg failed with $($rtn.returnvalue) ”
 }
if($rtn.rebootrequired) 
  { Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan “reboot required” }
```

Here is what I did

```
Function EnableDisable-OfflineFiles{
param($computer=”localhost”, $a, $help)

<# 
DESCRIPTION:
NAME: EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 
Enables or disables offline files on a local or remote machine.
A reboot of the machine MAY be required. This information will
be displayed in the status message once the script is run.

PARAMETERS: 
-computer Specifies name of the computer upon which to run the script
-a(ction) < e(nable), d(isable) >
-help     prints help file

SYNTAX:
EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -computer MunichServer -a e

Enables offline files on a computer named MunichServer

EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -a d

Disables offline files on local computer

EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -help ?

Displays the help topic for the script

“@
$helpText
#>
function funline ($strIN)
{
 $num = $strIN.length
 for($i=1 ; $i -le $num ; $i++)
  { $funline += “=” }
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor yellow $strIN 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor darkYellow $funline
}

function funHelp()
{
$helpText=@”
DESCRIPTION:
NAME: EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 
Enables or disables offline files on a local or remote machine.
A reboot of the machine MAY be required. This information will
be displayed in the status message once the script is run.

PARAMETERS: 
-computer Specifies name of the computer upon which to run the script
-a(ction) < e(nable), d(isable) >
-help     prints help file

SYNTAX:
EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -computer MunichServer -a e

Enables offline files on a computer named MunichServer

EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -a d

Disables offline files on local computer

EnableDisableOffLineFiles.ps1 -help ?

Displays the help topic for the script

“@
$helpText

}

function funtranslatemethod($a)
{
 switch($a)
  {
   “e” { $global:m = $true 
         $global:msg = “Enable offline files” 
       }
   “d” { 
        $global:m = $false
        $global:msg = “Disable offline files” 
       }
  default{ 
          $global:msg = “$a is not an allowed response`n” 
 }
  }
}

if($help){ funline(“Obtaining help …”) ; funhelp }
if(!$a)
   {
    $(throw “You must supply an action. try this:
EnableDIsableOfflineFiles.ps1 -help ?”)
   }
$global:msg =$global:m = $null
funtranslatemethod($a)

$objWMI = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OfflineFilesCache -Computer $computer
funline(“Configure Offline files on $computer …”)
$rtn = $objwmi.Enabled($m)
if($rtn.returnvalue -eq 0)
 {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor green “$msg succeeded”
 }
ELSE
 {
  Write-Host -ForegroundColor red “$msg failed with $($rtn.returnvalue) ”
 }
if($rtn.rebootrequired) 
  { Write-Host -ForegroundColor cyan “reboot required” }
}
```

I get this error when I run this function

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.ManagementObject]
> does not contain a method named 'Enabled'.
>
> - $rtn = $objwmi.Enabled($m)
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Enabled:String) [], RuntimeException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
>   ```

Comment: The layout of the question is a bit missed up but couldn't figure out how to change it. Sorry

Comment: It should be `$rtn = $objwmi.enable($m)` (not `.enabled`). As aside, I know the [original script](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-enable-and-disable-offline-files/) has them, but it is not advisable to use those ugly curly quotes in code (`“` and `”`). Replace them with straight quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like [the same question](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/mdxyld/enabledisable_offline_file_sync/gsjtoux/?context=3) I saw on reddit earlier this evening. I answered it over there but I'll give a brief answer here as well.

The error is that you're calling the method `Enabled`. `Enabled` is the name of a property of the `Win32_OfflineFilesCache` CIM class, indicating the current state. The method itself is named `Enable` - present tense - to set the state. The naming is pretty ambiguous, especially because it's also used to *disable* offline files.

To see the names of the methods and properties of a CIM class, use the `Get-CimClass` cmdlet.

```
Get-CimClass -ClassName Win32_OfflineFilesCache | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CimClassMethods

Name              ReturnType Parameters                               Qualifiers           
----              ---------- ----------                               ----------           
Enable                UInt32 {Enable, RebootRequired}                 {implemented, static}
RenameItem            UInt32 {NewPath, OriginalPath, ReplaceIfExists} {implemented, static}
RenameItemEx          UInt32 {NewPath, OriginalPath, ReplaceIfExists} {implemented, static}
Synchronize           UInt32 {Flags, Paths}                           {implemented, static}
Pin                   UInt32 {Deep, Flags, Paths}                     {implemented, static}
Unpin                 UInt32 {Deep, Flags, Paths}                     {implemented, static}
DeleteItems           UInt32 {Flags, Paths}                           {implemented, static}
Encrypt               UInt32 {Encrypt, Flags}                         {implemented, static}
SuspendRoot           UInt32 {Path, Suspend}                          {implemented, static}
TransitionOffline     UInt32 {Flags, Force, Path, OpenFiles}          {implemented, static}
TransitionOnline      UInt32 {Flags, Path}                            {implemented, static}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line that is failing is:

$rtn = $objwmi.Enabled($m)

You have a capital 'E' on Enabled.
What happens when you make that lowercase like in the original script.